# How to call android flavor gradle task from another task

Tags: android, gradle

In my project I have 3 product flavors (dev, production and testing). I've recently switched from Ant, so maybe I still have Ant mindset, but this is what I am trying to achieve:

create custom task (let's call it "buildAndUpload"), which will call assembleDevRelease and then call another task.

Here is what I've tried:

```
task myCustomTask {
  println "My Custom Task"
}

task buildAndUpload {
  tasks.assembleDevRelease.execute()
  tasks.myCustomTask.execute()
}
```

When I call buildAndUpload task (gradlew buildAndUpload) I am getting following output:

```
:buildAndUpload 
"My Custom Task"
```

As you can see assembleDevRelease task is not called. I know that I can use doLast closure, but I really want to have myCustomTask call contained in separate task.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A task cannot call another task, but it can depend on it. For example:

```
task myCustomTask {
    dependsOn "assembleDevRelease"
    doLast {
        println "executing..."
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should set the two tasks as dependencies. You'll want to do something along the lines of

```
task buildAndUpload(dependsOn: ['assembleDevRelease', 'myCustomTask'] {
}
```

Also please refer to the Gradle documentation on the build lifecycle for more details on execution order:
http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html

Comment: Is order of execution guaranteed in this case?